# DRA (Diameter Routing Agent) server

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, diameter-protocol

How the DRA (Diameter Routing Agent) server works ? .On what basis it is routing the traffic to the network nodes like OCS ,GGSN and PCRF.

Answer (score 0):

> 6.1.6.  Request Routing
>
> Diameter request message routing is done via realms and
> applications.    A Diameter message that may be forwarded by Diameter
> agents (proxies,    redirects or relays) MUST include the target realm
> in the    Destination-Realm AVP and one of the application
> identification AVPs    Auth-Application-Id, Acct-Application-Id or
> Vendor-Specific-    Application-Id.  The realm MAY be retrieved from
> the User-Name AVP,    which is in the form of a Network Access
> Identifier (NAI).  The realm    portion of the NAI is inserted in the
> Destination-Realm AVP.
>
> Diameter agents MAY have a list of locally supported realms and
> applications, and MAY have a list of externally supported realms and
> applications.  When a request is received that includes a realm
> and/or application that is not locally supported, the message is
> routed to the peer configured in the Realm Routing Table (see Section
> 2.7).

see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3588#page-74